# .NET Core and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I was reading through some of the microsoft .net core documentation and stumbled across this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/

Does the following quoted text (more specifically the last bullet point) imply that the MVC approach is no longer the recommended approach moving forward?  Is this just a microsoft thing or general for any development that was based on the MVC approach?

> This tutorial teaches ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework Core with
>   controllers and views. Razor Pages is a new alternative in ASP.NET
>   Core 2.0, a page-based programming model that makes building web UI
>   easier and more productive. We recommend the Razor Pages tutorial over
>   the MVC version. The Razor Pages tutorial:
>
> - Is easier to follow.
>
>   - Provides more EF Core best practices.
>   - Uses more efficient queries.
>   - Is more current with the lastest API.
>   - Covers more features.
>   - Is the preferred approach for new application development.

Comment: that's the way how things works with microsoft - every time they throw a new thing - they tell that everything you did before was wrong... i've seen it so many times during last 15 years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor Pages are *still* MVC, they just greatly simplify your code. Rather than having a distinct Model in one directory, a Controller in another directory, and a View in yet another directory, it keeps everything together in two files: A "View" (`.cshtml`) and a "Controler/Model" (`.cs`).

If you look at enough ASP.NET MVC applications you quickly notice how often there is a 1:1 relationship between the Views and their Controllers. In most cases, you find the Controller contains one method per View that consists of little more than `return View();`. Razor Pages helps solve this issue.

This does not change the fundamental value proposition of MVC and it's clear separation of concerns. It also isn't an either/or proposition. You can absolutely mix the traditional MVC structure and Razor Pages in the same web app.

Comment: Great. You confirm what I had actually noticed in terms of the .cs pretty much acting as a controller for the .cshtml.  I do like this new setup too in term of keeping things cleaner.  Perhaps with time and more projects I'll see cases where it could make sense to opt for the traditional approach.

Comment: In terms of mixing the two approaches though, how would that work?  I ask because the @page directive which makes a view a razor page also determines the routing.  Would you basically bypass that by for example using the asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" syntax even within a razor page?